# Date error Java Api

Tags: java, api, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm getting an error while passing the parameter 'date' to my java api, the code is the following for the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/horario/{fecha}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object queryHorariosLibres(@PathVariable("fecha") Date fecha) {
    List<Long> horariosLibres = null;
    List<Long> turnosTomados = turnoService.getTurnosTomados(fecha);
    Calendar dia = new GregorianCalendar();
    dia.setTime(fecha);
    Horario horario = horarioRepository.findByDia(dia.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));  
    horariosLibres = horario.getHorariosLibres(turnosTomados);
    if (horariosLibres == null) {
        return "hola";
    } else
    return horariosLibres;
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable java.util.Date for value '2016-02-15'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Here's the code for my model:
This is the "horario" class which manages hours :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "horario")
public class Horario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;
private Integer dia;
private Long horarioInicio;
private Long horarioFin;

Getters And Setter's

@Transient
public List<Long> getHorarios(){
    List<Long> horarios = new ArrayList<Long>();

    for(Long i = horarioInicio; i <= horarioFin; i+=300){
        horarios.add(i);
    }
    return horarios;

}

@Transient
public List<Long> getHorariosLibres(List<Long> horariosTomados){

    List<Long> horariosLibres = getHorarios();
    horariosLibres.removeAll(horariosTomados);

    return horariosLibres;

}

...
```

And this is the "turn / schedule" class that manages the appointments:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "turno")
public class Turno implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;
private String solicitante;
private String telefono;
private TipoDocumento tipoDocumento;
private String numeroDocumento;
private String email;
private Integer horario;
private String numeroTurno;
private Date fecha;
private String controlFecha;

Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: I would Really Really recommend to use joda-time's LocalDate instead of java.util.Date
Maybe it will also deserialize out of box.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the @DateTimeFormat annotation to your parameter.

> @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/horario/{fecha}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object queryHorariosLibres(@PathVariable("fecha") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date fecha) {
List<Long> horariosLibres = null;
List<Long> turnosTomados = turnoService.getTurnosTomados(fecha);
Calendar dia = new GregorianCalendar();
dia.setTime(fecha);
Horario horario = horarioRepository.findByDia(dia.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));  
horariosLibres = horario.getHorariosLibres(turnosTomados);
if (horariosLibres == null) {
    return "hola";
} else
return horariosLibres;
}
```

Comment: Exactly that. Forgot completely to format the date. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear

```
Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable java.util.Date for value '2016-02-15'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

`2016-02-15` cannot be converted to `Date` class, so it's treated as a String and cannot fit the signature. You should change that field in a way that can be automatically parsed by the controller